Infinite Loop Issue with Static Operators in Swift Extensions (Learning Purposes)
I'm encountering a problem with using both + and * static functions in a Swift extension. I just want + to be * and * to be +. When I use just the + operator, it works fine, but when I include both operators, I run into an infinite loop.
Works fine
extension Int {
    static func + (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return (left * right)
    }
}

// 12
print(3 + 4)
// 12
print(3 * 4)

Now is going into an infinite loop
extension Int {
    static func + (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return (left * right)
    }
    
    static func * (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return (left + right)
    }
}

print(3 + 4)
print(3 * 4)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cool trick for debugging use print(#function), see below in comments.

Somehow I need to save a local +? Similar to "swap two numbers"?

Question: When you do return (left + right) (left + right) is supposed to be which operation? The "real +" or the override "+" ? That's your issue.

Change the multiply to Int(Double(left) + Double(right)) and this will "fix" it, do you understand why?

@Larme How I viewed the whole thing is something like this: inside the body + and * are unchanged somehow (idk how +/* is created ). When I say static func + I was hoping that I maybe do some sort of shadowing it. So, + and * that came with the language maybe are unchanged, and my extension goes on top of that somehow, idk...

@JoakimDanielson so this means that there is a + for Int and one for double? Or something like how a method is allowed inside a class with the same name and different types? So there could be multiple pluses for every single type? (Not every single type but maybe for every single version of a different argument). But  I suppose + is an infix right?

Looks like print(3.0 + 4.0) returns 7.0. I wanted to do it just for Int, not like skip the Int * and use Double and then convert it back to Int. Maybe later I extend the function or whatever that does the conversion, and this thing is not going to work no more.

My suggestion was for int so still do 3 + 4. Just to check you do understand why you got an infinite loop, right?

@JoakimDanielson Got it. So this means that + is a function inside Int class, * is also a function inside Int class, now what I think is happening:

Some sort of mutual recursion thing?I think swift allows that, I definitely used it before.
Is all about the logic, and how it is redefined?


Idk why, but I think that maybe there is more to it, some deep code stuff. Maybe * is implemented using +?

Add print(#function) as the first line of each function and you will see that they call each other

Nice one, cool debugging. Looks like it does not have a base case to end the recursion. Again, I think that is just some deep stuff, because if I say 5 + 3 or 5 * 3 I do not reach a base case, I suppose the compiler(or Xcode or whatever) does that through some algorithms.

aaaaa so the base case for multiplication is different than addition so that's why is doing that because I reversed those 2?

This is not about the base case, and is about the call between * and +? so * is calling my * not the one in the build in code, and the same thing happens for +? So those two call each other and none of those will call the code the came with swift?

I just saw that you said that, I think you've edited your comment, because I don't think it was like that before.

@JoakimDanielson Is there a way to modify the actual + and * and not use a different infix operator, because here your doing stuff with functions not values. I'm not saying that have a local copy of + and then do some logic on that, Im saying directly on +.

Y’in + you call * and in * you call + : this will loop forever as either function call the other .

So here was the thing that I was looking for:
import Foundation

extension Int {    
    static func + (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return (left &* right)
    }
        
    static func * (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return (left &+ right)
    }
}


// 12
print(3 + 4)
// 7
print(3 * 4)


"In Swift, the &+, &-, and &* operators provide arithmetic operations that don't trap on overflow but instead wrap around using two's complement representation. This simulates how many lower-level languages (like C) handle arithmetic overflow and how hardware instructions for arithmetic operations work."

I have no clue whatever the above explanation means, if some1 can explain this in details that would be great. I know that &* is
overflow-safe multiplication but what it does, and how it is used by swift I do not know. Thanks (just comment under this answer).
EDIT
Check this video Fast Conversion From Cpp Floating Point Numbers - Cassio Neri - C++Now 2024 good stuff in there. Maybe somehow this works like that, If some1 could elaborate on this thing that would be amazing.
Some additional info:
Overflow Operators, and this also Table of 4-bit Binary System With the TWOs Complement Method


&: The & operator performs multiplication and allows for overflow. In Swift, when integer operations overflow, the result wraps around using two's complement arithmetic. This means that if the result exceeds the maximum representable value, it wraps around to the minimum representable value, and vice versa.



&+: Similarly, the &+ operator performs addition and allows for overflow. It also wraps around using two's complement arithmetic if the result exceeds the representable range of the type.


More details are welcomed!

The two operators you declared in the extensions keep on calling each other. The easiest way to avoid this is to not use + or * in the bodies of those operators.
We want a way to call the built-in + and *, even in the presence of the extension. Luckily, + and * in Int are protocol witnesses to the + and * requirements in the Numeric protocol. We can call + and * through Numeric:
// * and + in these functions will not resolve to the ones you declared in the extension
func add<T: Numeric>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: T) -> T {
    lhs + rhs
}
func multiply<T: Numeric>(_ lhs: T, _ rhs: T) -> T {
    lhs * rhs
}

// your custom + and * operators can be implemented with the above functions
extension Int {
    static func + (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return multiply(left, right)
    }
    
    static func * (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return add(left, right)
    }
}

Of course, the same approach will not work if you want to swap + and * for every Numeric type, but this trick does work for any type that is "more specific" than Numeric, like FloatingPoint, SignedNumeric etc.

Please post an answer if you got a better one (looking to modify built-in + and built-in *).
infix operator ++
infix operator **

extension Int {
    static func ++ (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return (left * right)
    }
    
    static func ** (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int {
        return (left + right)
    }
}



// 12
print(3 ++ 4)
// 7
print(3 ** 4)

Extension inside a function is not allowed (Declaration is only valid at file scope) so swift does not allow the reassignment or shadowing of operators within local scopes, so if some1 came with a solution is much appreciated.
